# Why do these Python import scenarios work (or not) the way they do?

Tags: python, import

Suppose a repository has a directory called `./example` with an `__init__.py` file to signal that it is a package.
The tests are in `./tests`, which does *not* have an `__init__.py` file:

```py
.
|-- README.md
|-- example
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- func.py
|-- setup.py
`-- tests
    `-- test_hello.py
```

`./example/func.py` is pretty simple:

```py
def hello():
    return "hello!"
```

If I run an interactive interpreter in the root directory I can import `example`:

```
$ python
>>> import example
>>> example.hello()
'hello!'
```

I can also put a script in the root directory that imports `example`:

```
$ cat > temp.py
import example
print(example.hello())
^D

$ python temp.py
hello!
```

Here's where things get odd. If I run `pytest` in the root directory with no arguments it fails to import `example`:

```
$ pytest
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/gregwilson/example/tests/test_hello.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../conda/envs/stjs/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_hello.py:1: in <module>
    import example
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

However, if I run `python -m pytest` in the root directory it works:

```
$ python -m pytest
collected 1 item
tests/test_hello.py .
```

If I now add an empty file `tests/__init__.py`, the tests work both ways:

```
$ touch tests/_init__.py

$ python -m pytest
collected 1 item
tests/test_hello.py .

$ pytest
collected 1 item
tests/test_hello.py .
```

My questions are:

1. Why does `pytest` fail but `python -m pytest` work before I add `./tests/__init__.py`?
2. Why does adding an `__init__.py` file to `tests` make `pytest` on its own work?

But wait, it gets weirder.
I can make a directory `./temp` and add a file `./temp/temp.py` that imports `example` and tries to use it:

```
$ mkdir temp

$ cat > temp/temp.py
import example
print(example.hello())
^D
```

Running that directly doesn't work:

```
$ python temp/temp.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

Running it with `python -m` does:

```
$ python -m temp.temp
hello!
```

But unlike the `tests` case, adding an `__init__.py` file to `./temp` *doesn't* make it work:

```
$ touch temp/__init__.py

$ python temp/temp.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

I'd be grateful if someone could explain what's going on here.

Comment: Is `example/__init__.py` empty? I get `module 'example' has no attribute 'hello'` when I try `import example; example.hello()`

Comment: In https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options there is for `-m` the info "As with the -c option, the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.". I guess that it is pytest that removes the current directory from `sys.path`.

Comment: Adding `import sys ; with open('/tmp/eefromtest.txt', 'w') as f:     print(f"sys.path {sys.path}", file=f)` confirms that the directory of execution is in `sys.path` when running as `-m` and not as `pytest`. Python 3.9 Linux.

Comment: pytest is distributed as a "shebang" python program that import the "main" so that the current directory is simply not imported. I realize that this is only a partial reply to 1.

Comment: Still on "1": pytest uses importlib and they describe the behaviour as follows: if the test is in a module (thus there is the `__init__.py` file), it will look up and add the root of the project define as the level that contains a directory with a `__init__.py` file (so one level "up" from the last `__init__.py`).

Practical solutions: install the package before testing or (if a pure python package) add `.` to `PYTHONPATH` before running.

Comment: missing link, sorry: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html?highlight=module#test-modules-conftest-py-files-inside-packages